# Trying to pull fetched data out of Browserify bundle

Tags: node.js, browserify

I am new to Browserify/Node.js and I have been trying to use npm to pull data. My code for pulling the data in one js file, main.js, is:

```
const { getChart } = require('billboard-top-100');
var artistArray = [];

getChart('artist-100', '', (err, chart) => {
    if (err) console.log(err);
    for (let i = 0; i < 100; i++) {
    artistArray.push(chart.songs[i].artist)
    }
    console.log(artistArray);
    return artistArray;
});
```

I then bundled this file with Browserify to be able to access it in my HTML code in a separate js file, bundle.js.

Although I am able to console.log the artistArray variable and execute terminal command >node main.js, which successfully displays the artistArray, I am unable to get the variable in my main html file. Any help?

I've tried everything. Sorry if this question is dumb, I'm a beginner.

Answer (score 0):

```
const { getChart } = require('billboard-top-100');
var artistArray = [];

getChart('artist-100', '', (err, chart) => {
    if (err) console.log(err);
    for (let i = 0; i < 100; i++) {
    artistArray.push(chart.songs[i].artist)
    }
    console.log(artistArray);
    return artistArray;
});

console.log(artistArray) // <- this will print []
```

If you call `artistArray` outside the callback function `(err, chart) => {...}`, then you will get the same value as you init. Because at that moment, you don't have data from `getChart` yet. So you can only using it inside the callback function.

To sum up:

- return `artistArray` in callback function is useless here.
- You can only use the data inside that callback function

```
const { getChart } = require('billboard-top-100');
var artistArray = [];

getChart('artist-100', '', (err, chart) => {
    if (err) console.log(err);
    for (let i = 0; i < 100; i++) {
    artistArray.push(chart.songs[i].artist)
    }
    // Using the artistArray direct here.
});
```

- or it has a trick that you can use `setTimeout` with the `delay` you think that is safe enough for `getChart` done the data.

```
...
getChart(..., '' , (err, chart)=> {...})
setTimeout(() => {
  console.log(artistArray) // <- data after updated
}, 3000) // <- waiting 3 second
```

For me, to handle this. I usually build a function that has input is an array we want to process and put all logic there. And then put it to the callback.

```
getChart('artist-100', '', (err, chart) => {
  if (err) console.log(err);
       for (let i = 0; i < 100; i++) {
      artistArray.push(chart.songs[i].artist)
  }
  handleList(artistArray)
})

function handleList(arr) {
  // your code logic with artistArray here
}
```